# Django will play some videos and not others

Tags: python, django, video

I've got a couple of videos I'm trying to play through a Django app.  This one

```
<video width="500" height="355" controls>
    <source src="{% static 'vid/getting%20started.mp4' %}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

produces this html and works

```
<video width="500" height="355" controls>
     <source src="/static_url/vid/getting%2520started.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This one

```
<video width="500" height="355" controls>
    <source src="{% static module.module_key.url %}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

produces this html and doesn't work

```
<video width="500" height="355" controls>
    <source src="/static_url/vid/gsc.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

In this case the field module.module_key.url contains "vid/gsc.mp4"

Why doesn't the second video run?

Comment: Are you able to get the same video at `http://your-server/static_url/vid/gsc.mp4`? Are you running django development server or some other server like Nginx or Apache?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Django really.. as the HTML is both the same just a different URL. Either the video isn't supported in your browser or it doesn't exist.

Comment: Which error does it give?

Comment: I'm running it on Apache and it doesn't give an error.  IT takes about a minute to try and load the file then does nothing.  The video is ok because I've tried just running it from my pc and I've loaded it into youtube and run from there.  I simply cannot get it to run as a static file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've concluded this must be down to file size.  I've set up a separate website to host the video files and I call them from the django app.  Works perfectly.